# Msg 8114 : Error converting data type timestamp to datetime in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Someone in our team wrote the following query years ago

```
    create table #tempDocumentCategory (documentcategorycodeidno int , documentcategorycode varchar(50), documentcategorycodedescription varchar(200), timestamp datetime,Inactive bit)
    insert #tempDocumentCategory(documentcategorycodeidno  , documentcategorycode , documentcategorycodedescription , timestamp ,Inactive )
    exec sp_getDocumentCategoriesCodesCtrl 1
```

Now this exec sp_getDocumentCategoriesCodesCtrl returns a timestamp which is then stored in the datetime type column in the temporary table created above. We never recieved any problem until recently a customer raised an issue stating that the page is crashing with an error message stating "Error Converting data type timestamp to datetime".

Now, I understand that a timestamp is not a datetime and is not being used here as such. As far as I can check I see that the datetime and Timestamp both have same size - bytes(8). I want to know why timestamp didn't convert to datetime automatically and What am I missing/misinterpreting here. Pardon if this is a stupid question, I am fairly new to SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getDocumentCategoriesCodesCtrl
@ShowAllInd bit = 0
AS
/* Select record set */
IF @ShowAllInd = 0
   SELECT
      DocumentCategoryCodeIdNo,
      DocumentCategoryCode,
      DocumentCategoryCodeDescription,
      Timestamp,
      CAST(0 as BIT) as Inactive
   FROM tDocumentCategory_Codes
   WHERE 
      (DocumentCategoryCodeToEffectDate = '01/01/3000')
   ORDER BY DocumentCategoryCode
ELSE
   SELECT
      DocumentCategoryCodeIdNo,
      DocumentCategoryCode,
      DocumentCategoryCodeDescription,
      Timestamp,
      Inactive =
         CASE WHEN DocumentCategoryCodeToEffectDate <> '01/01/3000' THEN CAST(1 as BIT)
         ELSE CAST(0 as BIT)
         END
   FROM tDocumentCategory_Codes
   ORDER BY DocumentCategoryCode
RETURN(0)
```

Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tDocumentCategory_Codes](
    [DocumentCategoryCodeIdNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentCategoryCodeDomainIdNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentCategoryCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DocumentCategoryCodeDescription] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [DocumentCategoryCodeFromEffectDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentCategoryCodeToEffectDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LanguageId] [char](5) NULL,
    [DocumentCategoryCodeDefaultCodeInd] [bit] NULL,
    [Timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tDocumentCategory_Codes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentCategoryCodeIdNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Please paste [sp_getDocumentCategoriesCodesCtrl] code here.

Comment: sp_getDocumentCategoriesCodesCtrl definition pasted :)

Comment: Thanks :) Now I need table [tDocumentCategory_Codes] create script

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. Table definition Added

Comment: I posted answer. Timestamp cannot be converted to datetime. They do not have any relations. At some cases cast will success, but, received date is random value. Unusefull info... 

If you need to have datetime, you need to alter your table [tDocumentCategory_Codes], change [timestamp] column type to DATETIME, and then set default value (GETDATE()). At this case you can use DATETIME format  in #tempDocumentCategory and get your desired result

Comment: Is there any reasoning behind when it is casted successfully and when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing data in [timestamp] column with data type timestamp.
Data type timestamp does not have any relations with datetime data type. Timestamp is just automaticaly incremented value on database. So, wrong decision is to convert timestamp to datetime. You can solve your problem in following way:

```
   create table #tempDocumentCategory(
          documentcategorycodeidno int 
         ,documentcategorycode varchar(50)
         ,documentcategorycodedescription varchar(200)
         ,timestamp VARBINARY(8)
         ,Inactive bit
    )
```

If you need to have datetime, you need to alter your table [tDocumentCategory_Codes], change [timestamp] column type to DATETIME, and then set default value (GETDATE()). At this case you can use DATETIME format in #tempDocumentCategory and get your desired result

Comment: I have solved the problem by completely removing timestamp as it was not required on this page but I need to know why it couldn't convert it this time and why was it converting most of the time. I need to know when is a timestamp converted to datetime and when not. Does that makes sense?

Comment: TIMESTAMP is just increment value on database, and does not have any relations with date. More about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=SQL.90).aspx

So, bad news here, if you need convert old timestamp values to datetime. Its impossible :(

Comment: P.s. answering your question about the some cases, when convert possible:

At some times you can convert increment value (f.e. INT) to datetime. 
Example: select cast(1234567 as datetime). Result is unpredictable.
But, when database automatic counter reaches value X, convert is impossible. Example: select cast(12345678 as datetime)

Comment: That makes sense :) Thank you.